Consequences of a Character Being Unaffected by Gravitational Force?
In a world where a character gains the ability to be unaffected by gravitational forces due to true magic runes,
the first scenario I thought of was : The character is launched toward a library wall at high speeds due to the Earth's rotational and orbital velocities. The character’s internal matter remains intact due to the limitations of the magic, but they are unaffected by gravity.
But also a second Scenario is
In this scenario, the character, unaffected by gravitational force, instead phases through the library wall and continues moving outward from the solar system. As gravity has no effect on their trajectory, they would essentially move unimpeded through space. The character would not experience any deceleration from the impact, leading to a continuous, uninterrupted motion through the fabric of the universe.
Which of the two scenario is more?
What immediate effects would occur upon impact with the library wall, considering the high speed and the lack of gravitational force?
How would the surrounding environment be affected by the character's trajectory and impact? What level of destruction would be observed in the immediate vicinity?
How quickly would these events transpire, and would any bystanders or witnesses be able to perceive and react to the character's movement and impact in any meaningful way?

Welcome to worldbuilding, please read our [help], it clearly states that questions along the line of "what if X happened?" are a poor fit for us. We prefer a well defined worldbuilding problem.

@L.Dutch thank you for your guidance should I edit this question to fit the guidelines or create a new one? and close this one?

Please edit this one

You edit hasn't improved the situation. Ask only 1 question with a rather narrow scope and answerable in a measurable way.

@L.Dutch would just asking which of the two scenario be more realistic or do I need to elaborate more on the scenario

You seem to conflate inertia and gravity, they are different things. Can you clarify exactly what the question is.

H.G.Wells gives a fair description of weightlessness and buoyancy in his short story "The Truth about Pyecraft".

Neither of these situations would occur. Gravity isn't what stops you from phasing through walls, that's electromagnetism. You also wouldn't shoot off at 1000km/h because a spell that stops gravity from affecting you won't remove your inertia relative to an arbitrary reference frame.
Here's what would happen:
The bouyant force would cause your character to  accelerate upwards, to higher and higher altitudes, where they would either suffocate or freeze to death. Eventually they leave the atmosphere, the Earth, and even the solar system behind, their corpse floating through deep space.

This is simply wrong: it's gravity that prevents you from flying off along the tangent because of the planet rotation. Buoyancy is irrelevant.

@L.Dutch yes, I am quite aware that it is gravity that pulls us towards Earth (thanks for reminding me). You're still very much wrong though, buoyancy is entirely relevant, and would be the primary force that causes you to detach from the Earth. The rate at which the Earth would curve away from you due to its orbit would be much slower, and would only occur if you were on the night or dusk side of the planet

The question states that the subject is in the vicinity of a library wall - if they are inside an enclosed building then the outcome is much less dire.  They would just slowly float around inside until they can get a grip on something.

@KerrAvon2055 true, although to be very pedantic they only specified that the character flies through a library wall, not whether they are on the inside or outside of that wall. Edit: which you did mention, so nvm

As long as their clothing isn’t also immune to gravity, it should be easy to stick to the ground by simply wearing heavy shoes.

wouldn't his inertia cause him to continue in a straight line tangential to the earth's surface (if no library ceiling is in the way) though? the earth rotates, and the only thing keeping him attacked (barring ceilings) is gravity - so I'd imagine he'd get slung away like someone cut the chains on a merry-go-round (in zero gravity).

While their buoyancy may play a part they would still leave the planet (and fast) in the absence of any atmosphere. Assuming they aren't at the pole they have a significant sideways motion and now no gravity to make them continue their curved journey around the planet. So they would continue in the straight line path they were on before

The buoyancy force is a good catch. They and anything they affect would be as buoyant as the same volume of vacuum. Yes, Earth's rotation will be an issue, but that will only add 0.003 g of apparent acceleration. Though it's not obvious if their inertial mass is affected along with their gravitational mass...but negating inertial mass would probably be very lethal, considering what it'd do to molecular motions.

@RichardTingle the centrifugal force, even at the equator, is miniscule relative to the buoyant force

@Syndic keep in mind this merrry-go-round has an RPM of  0.000694

Having seen this argument and then put together a quick Python simulation of a body suddenly losing its connection to gravity, I can confirm that it will fly off tangent to the Earth's surface without gravity pulling it down to the surface. Buoyancy will be significant, but the Earth's surface rotates fast enough that it will be only a minor factor compared to suddenly not falling back down to the Earth. In the event of an intervening surface (i.e. library), buoyancy will be the most important factor, but otherwise, the lack of gravity will cause them to leave the planet fast.

@controlgroup really? Multiple sources (e.g: https://geo.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Meteorology_and_Climate_Science/Book%3A_Fundamentals_of_Atmospheric_Science_(Brune)/10%3A_Dynamics_-_Forces/10.05%3A_Effects_of_Earth%E2%80%99s_Rotation-_Apparent_Forces#:~:text=The%20centrifugal%20force%20at%20the,the%20equator%20and%20the%20poles.) state an acceleration of 0.033 m/s/s, which is miniscule. Numbers on the bouyant force are more scarce, but one source states around 2g, and anecdotally, anyone's who's released a helium balloon knows the acceleration is way higher than 0.03 m/s/s

@controlgroup of course, objects accelerating under the bouyant force hit a speed cap very quickly, but that applies equally to the centrifugal force

@MS I should have clarified; yes the buoyant force is significant at lower altitudes but of course it eventually falls off as atmospheric pressure goes down, whereas "centrifugal force" (an artifact of a rotating frame of reference) continues forever. Over a longer period the biggest contribution is from CF, while buoyancy is more important at smaller timescales.

"I'd imagine he'd get slung away like someone cut the chains on a merry-go-round" - you are vastly underestimating the size of the Earth.   The acceleration due to that effect  at mid-latitudes is less than one inch per second per second.  In about 5 minutes it would accumulate to about the same speed as you would reach falling after one second in normal gravity, if you hadn't reached the equivalent of terminal velocity due to air resistance before that.

First, welcome to worldbuilding. For future reference, please keep in mind that asking more than one question is literally a reason to close questions. You're allowed to ask one and only one question.
What would happen? Well... neither option you propose is correct.
Your character would immediately be weightless, but your character is also moving at the same speeds as the Earth (which is rotating, orbiting, and moving along the orbit of the sun through the galaxy, among other things), so immediately nothing happens other than your character might barf due to the sudden loss of weight. But, what happens next?

If your character is outside, and given enough time, your character will eventually start moving toward space. This is due to centrifugal force caused by the Earth spinning. Gravity holds you down, centrifugal force pushes you up. Spin a planet fast enough and centrifugal force overwhelms gravity. Slow it down and gravity overwhelms centrifugal force. But we just removed gravity, so eventually your character will begin to move away from the planet. If I remember my physics correctly (could be wrong about this), the effect would be faster at the poles where the spin is also faster. Could be wrong about that, though. Someone check my proverbial math, please.

However, probably long before #1 happens, your character is going to do something very normal. They'll take a step. Leg muscles trained to push against the force of gravity will push your character away from the surface. To be fair, your legs don't really push against the full force of gravity (9.8 m/s), one leg acts like a pivot while the other swings forward — and it's the very light push of the first combined with the much stronger swing of the second that will start things moving. The character, now out of control, unless they grab something, will bounce of a few things and eventually end up in space. Lots and lots of space. Hope they didn't use that rune while playing basketball hoping it would give them a magnificent jump shot — because it will. Once.

But let's assume your character knows what's about to happen and chooses to hang onto something? There are other effects to contend with! Wind, for example, will begin to push your character around like a leaf. Someone jostling your character would do the same thing. Getting bumped by a friendly dog would, too. Remember Newton's laws of motion? One tells us that an object in motion stays in motion unless acted upon by an outside force. Like a dog. Yeah, anything that can happen to your character physically will cause your character to start moving — and the moment they've moved beyond the ability to grab hold of something... space. Lots and lots of space.

But what if we're inside a building? Would this be like a bouncy house or a warehouse full of trampolines? Nope. OK, well, kinda. As soon as your character starts moving (and if they don't grab onto something) they'll start bouncing off of things. They could get pretty bruised up! Note that if your character holds themselves still they'd eventually stop moving due to energy lost with each impact and air resistance... but where would that be? Could be anywhere inside the room.


If you want a rough idea of what all that's like, check out this video from the Canadian band OK GO and remember that despite what they say, it really isn't zero-G. There's microgravity as well as the plane's motion... but it's a close enough example for government work.
Finally, just for fun (remember my first admonition! This is a courtesy!) what would people do? Per the Help Center, we don't answer questions about character or organization decisions or actions because they can be anything you want. People are that varied... but in general... I expect that people would be so surprised by some dude or lady suddenly starting to float away that they might not be able to react fast enough to do a darn thing about it. If they're lucky, what could they do? Grab hold. It won't be easy because weightless doesn't mean massless. If a 100kg human is moving away at 9.8 m/s and that person is grabbed by another 100kg human who's held down by gravity the two would cancel each other out (after a gut-wrenching tug), but any motion by the first person would be whomping hard for the second to stop. But what if the second person is only 50kg? They'll both leave the surface at a slower speed because all that mass is there, and in motion, and the first wasn't acted upon by enough of the second. Of course that depends on how fast the first was moving.
What a gloriously complicated mess!

"You're allowed to ask one and only one question" "Per the Help Center, we don't answer questions about character or organization".. yet you answered. What example have you given to this user?

You've got the centrifugal and centripetal forces mixed up. Centrifugal = away from center, centripetal = towards center. When an object is moving in a circle (such as anything on the surface of the earth), the centripetal force is the inwards directed force keeping it in a circular trajectory. For an object on the ground, gravity provides the centripetal force required to keep it from moving in a straight line out to space.
If gravity disappeared for a person, a centrifugal force would appear to pull the person off the surface.

@L.Dutch At the time I answered, the OP had a reputation of one and no badges. I do try to be nice to the new users.

@sondre99v I'm not surprised! My focus is electronics. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll update the answer.

@JBH do you realize that by doing so 1) you don't help the new user to understand how the community work 2) you perpetuate the confusion because other users will see this LQ question getting answered and seeing it as a precedent for yet another LQ question?

No, @L.Dutch, I disagree with that - unless you're prepared to completely remove Frame Challenges - and I've been chastised for rapidly closing worse questions than this, so periodically I frankly expect to be forgiven for letting a Rep-1/0-badge user survive.

I agree with the above answers, but I would like to add another perspective: Gravitational forces as you discuss them are an effect of the theory of General Relativity (GR). Basically, Newton's gravitation emerges from GR when the speeds of moving objects are small compared to the speed of light. Think of it as GR being the larger, more general theory and Newton's gravity a special case that works well from our point of view.
GR is a fascinating theory that is based on the observations that light always travels at the same speed, that nothing can go faster than light and that gravitational forces are actually inertial forces in a curved space-time. GR ties together motion, gravity and causality. For example, if you could go faster than light, then you could travel in time.
If the spell kills GR effects, then I imagine that it would look like Newton's gravity is switched off at first, but GR anomalies would build up over time and lead to crazy stuff. The spell could do all sorts for interesting things. For example, the character could start seeing the future and/or the past. Or, they could create black holes (accidentally or on purpose). The situation could degenerate so badly that they end up casting the spell on themselves and start the whole thing. They could even decide to stop the expansion of the universe, cause another big bang or encode a message in the Cosmic microwave background.
